# Setting java_opts to tomcat service from command line

Tags: tomcat, windows-7, service, java-opts

I have a tomcat7 service running on windows,
Usually in order to configure the Java options I go to Tomcat 7.0\bin\tomcat7w.exe and there in java tab, in java options I print the definition I want, for example -javaagent:...
I want to do this through command line or using some script to have it automated, is there any way to achieve this and still run the tomcat as a service? (right now I run tomcat through cmd: "sc tomcat7 start").

Thanks

Comment: Tomcat has a configuration UI. See details:[Tomcat deployment configuration as service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530484)

Answer (score 4):

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Updating_services

You can run something like the following (the first "`tomcat7.exe`" is the service executable name, and the second "`//US//tomcat7`" is the service name prefixed with `//US//`, meaning "update service"):

```
tomcat7.exe //US//tomcat7 "--JvmOptions=-Xrs;-javaagent:xyz"
```

The values passed with the `--JvmOptions` flag are semicolon separated `JAVA_OPTS` flags. If you do this while the service is not running, i.e. before you execute:

```
sc.exe tomcat7 start
```

then it will affect subsequent starts of that "tomcat7" Tomcat service.