# SOLR configuration troule

Tags: java, tomcat, solr

I am following the tutorial "Running Nutch and Solr on Windows Tutorial" (Part 1) from Youtube and trying to configure properly Solr. I make the change in the C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\solr\WEB-INF\web.xml file as explained in the tutorial - putting the solr home path:

```
<env-entry-value>C:\cygwin64\home\solr\example\solr</env-entry-value>
```

And I gain in the browser:

```
    HTTP Status 500 - {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Error opening new searcher,
trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init 
failure: Error opening new searcher at 
org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:745) at 
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:307) at ...
```

When I copy the content of the folder C:\cygwin64\home\solr\example\solr to a new folder at C:\solr and the change the solr path to:

```
<env-entry-value>C:\solr</env-entry-value>
```

it works fine. It is the same situation when I Set the Java system property solr.solr.home my Solr Home:Windows > Start > Monitor Tomcat > Java Tab > Java Options -> Enter the following entry:

```
-Dsolr.solr.home=c:\solr
```

It works fine in this cae, but not when I put:

```
-Dsolr.solr.homeC:\cygwin64\home\solr\example\solr
```

I want solr to work under cygwin as in the tutorial, since it might be needed in that folder later, and I can't get it where could be the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like solr\home is not configured properly.

Comment: it seems that is the problem, but how can I configure for C:\cygwin64\home\solr\example\solr?

Comment: `<env-entry>
   <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
   <env-entry-value>C:\cygwin64\home\solr\example\solr</env-entry-value>
   <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>`

Comment: helpful post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619809/installing-apache-solr-4-3-1-on-apache-tomcat-6-0)

Comment: It is exactly what I am doing, but when I put "<env-entry-value>C:\cygwin64\home\solr\example\solr</env-entry-value>", it makes problem. When I put  "<env-entry-value>C:\solr</env-entry-value>" it doesn't.

Comment: -Dsolr.solr.homeC:\cygwin64\home\solr\example\solr looks like you are missing '=' in this. could you please recheck if this is the problem. should have been -Dsolr.solr.home=C:\cygwin64\home\solr\example\solr

Comment: No, this is by mistake put so in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, it was about file permissions at Cygwin folder, the Solr coludn't create folders. I changed manually the access rights.

Comment: ya i guess that was the problem. anyways happy debugging :)