# Tomcat deployment configuration as service

Tags: java, tomcat, setup-deployment

I am currently investigating how to deploy Tomcat as a windows service with some configuration settings. Without using System Environment Variables, how can I specify the location of the JRE (I'm bundling it with my Tomcat distribution)? Also, how can I set the heap min and max sizes for Tomcat?

So far I've run the "service.bat" batch file with some added arguments like:

> service.bat ServiceName //US//tomcat7 --JvmMs512–JvmMx1024

to attempt to set the heap sizes. This does not seem to be working.

EDIT:
I've been using the following commands now that I understand them more:

> tomcat7 //US//Test --JavaHome=PathToJRE --JvmMs=512 --JvmMx=1024

This still does not work. I'm verifying that it doesn't because I've uninstalled Java off of the host machine.
Here is the location where I'm getting the information: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

It is my understanding that when deploying Tomcat as a service, "setenv.bat" and "setclasspath.bat" don't actually get executed. Please correct me if I am wrong, because that would be my easiest solution. Also what does get executed in terms of the batch files located inside tomcat/bin when you install Tomcat as a service using "service.bat" to do it?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used the archive setup of tomcat then you the file catalina.bat (tomcat\bin\catalina.bat) where you can add your extra configuration:
    SET JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m 
    -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m 
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256m”

If you have installed tomcat using the installer provided for windows then you will not have this file. In this case you can use the tomcat7w.exe (also from tomcat\bin) where in the Java tab you can set up all that you want (this second option also works for the first case).

Comment: Yes. but keep in mind that if you want to use tomcat7w.exe the word from the file name before the "w" needs to be the name of your service [tomcat_service_name]w.exe (you can simply rename the file if it's not your case)

Comment: I was able to get that to work, by renaming the file, verified that JVM and Classpath, but it won't start if Java is not installed on the host machine. Do you know if having Java installed is required? I want my deployment to be independent of the settings and configurations of the host machine. Thanks for the speedy replies.

Comment: It doesn't need to be installed (using the installer) but you need at least jre to run apache tomcat. When you say you have verified JVM and Clashpath are you refering at the paths from the java tab in tomcatw.exe?